# Why does my accessory button move to the left for taller table cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table in my iOS app with three table cells, and they each have a custom Accessory button. One of the cells needs to be taller than the others; it is 60px instead of 45px. In this case, the accessory button gets scooted over to the left, whereas if they were all the same height, the accessory button would line up.

The accessory buttons are created by the same code, so they should be identical. The issue seems to be related to the UITableViewCell itself.

It ends up looking like this. I failed to include the upper border in the screen grab, but the upper cell is the taller one. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

[image: Misaligned accessory views:]

Here's an example of how the cells are created. These differ only in name; the height is specified by tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:[cell frame]];
    [label setText:@"Favorites"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GT.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [cell setAccessoryView:button];
```

Comment: How are you adding them to the table? show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code.

Comment: I have a project I just started yesterday actually with different sized cells and my accessories line up perfectly. See this screenshot: http://snapplr.com/mcbb

Comment: I've added some of the code. I assume I'm making some kind of rookie mistake, hopefully the code will make it obvious to someone with more experience.

Comment: I've been told to use a custom image for the accessory button. Setting only the accessory type solves the problem, but doesn't allow me to use the custom graphic. Removing the custom graphic does solve the problem, so if I have to, I will push argue that I need to use the standard graphic.

Comment: As far as the rest of the code goes, I build an NSArray of cells and then cellForRowAtIndexPath just returns the cell for that index of the array. Is there any harm in doing so? Otherwise I just have to write a switch statement in cellForRowAtIndexPath, which doesn't seem any cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the accessory view and the accessory type. **Do one or the other.** I would get rid of `setAccessoryView:button`.

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
[cell setAccessoryView:button];
```

Also, why are you doing this:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
```

You should be creating your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you should having something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Some Text";
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and will accept it if no one else chimes in with a solution for the custom accessory image as it does solve the problem if I end up going that way. It seems like it should be doable somehow without too much kludge, though.